# Uploading a large WAR file to Cloud Foundry fails

Tags: java, spring, cloud-foundry

When attempting a vmc push I get:

```
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (301M): OK      
HTTP exception: Errno::EPIPE:Broken pipe
```

The only advice out there on this issue seems to be to [reduce the application size](http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20235341-http-exception-errno-epipe-broken-pipe).

There is no way to reduce my application size. It depends on a very large data file. Is there any way to deploy an application of this size to Cloud Foundry? The filesystem limits seem to permit it, if I can just get the file transfered.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the log files? `vmc logs <app-name>`

Also I would prefer you try to deploy your app on a Micro Cloud so that you can SSH into it and look at whats going on. If you still have issues, the best thing to do is to open a case with the support team at Cloud Foundry - http://support.cloudfoundry.com. That way you can share your war file with the support agents and have them look into your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll do that.